# Reordering two columns using a third one

Tags: r

I have a df like:

```
chr11   1757418 1754950 ERR164550   4   +
chr1    116399450   116400907   ERR164550   3   -
...
```

Looking at the last column (`+` or `-`, in this case) I would like to reorder the second and the third variable. If the last column is a `-` then the values should stay that way. If the last column is a `+` then I would like to invert the values of the given row.

I could re-ask the question in another way: I would like to reoder to column 2 and 3 in every row and keeping the lowest value in column 2 and the highest in 3.

Any thoughs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the +/- column:

```
df[,2:3]=t(apply(df[,2:3],1,sort))
```